# what's the difference between Japa and namasmarana?

Tags: mantras, dvaita, japa, nama-japa

my current understanding is that namasmarana is a form of mental japa which is often accompanied by visualization of the rupa pair of the nama, please correct me here

thanks

Comment: Japa is done of a mantra of a particular deity while namasmarana is done of the name of that deity. Japa can be performed only by the person who has been initiated into the mantra but namasmarana can be done by the uninitiated too. For example repeating the name Vāsudeva is namasmarana but repeating the 12-lettered Vāsudeva mantra 'ॐ नमो भगवते वासुदेवाय' is japa. Only Ramanandis & Gaudiya Vaishnavas equate namasmarana with japa because the words 'Rāma' & 'Kṛṣṇa' are considered as mantras in Tantrika compendiums. You seems to have confused the 2 Sanskrit terms with the English term recitation.